# Hibernate Query Class Cast Exception

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables Topic and Members.Members comprises of the member who created the topic
Topic has an internal mapping for Members

The  following HQL query works in a Hibernate editor

```
    select  m from Topic as t inner join T.Members m where t.title = 'World News'
```

When it comes to the Java side of the implementation

```
    Object o= session.createQuery("select  m.username,m.membergroup from Topic as t inner
              join t.members m  where t.title = '"+topicTitle+"'");
    Members members=(Members)o;
```

Exception:

```
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to 
    phase.util.db.hbm.object.Members
    at phase.testdevel.ScheduleJob.getMemberDetails(ScheduleJob.java:312)
    at phase.testdevel.ScheduleJob.main(ScheduleJob.java:364)
```

Am new to Hibernate.Would appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.createQuery` gives you a query- Object and the you have to call list go get a List of `Members`

Change your code to:

```
 Query o= session.createQuery("select  m.username,m.membergroup from Topic as t inner
              join t.members m  where t.title = '"+topicTitle+"'");
    List<Members> members=o.list();
    if (members != null && members.size()>0){
       return members.get(0);
    } else {
       return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Select does return a list.But Query Object does not have a getList() method.Also List does not have a getSize() method.I changed the Hibernate Query to get the answer and then called list() on the select query.

Comment: @Sher sorry my fault. I have changed my post.